# AWS - EBS Attached But Can't Find On Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am pretty new to Amazon Web Services. I made my first EBS volume (through both the command line and the AWS web app) and attached it to a running instance at `/dev/sdh` as [seen here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663). The web app shows me that it has been successfully attached to the instance. However, the folder `/dev/sdh` does not show up on the instance, nor does `df -h` reveal that it is there. What else do I need to do?

I am not sure if this helps, but the instance is an Ubuntu 11.04 Large.

Comment: Did you attempt to format or mount it?  If so, what happened when you tried to mount it?

Comment: @Iterator - I got to this step in the linked document: `sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh`.  At this point it fails because /dev/sdh doesn't exist.

Comment: @Iterator - I already have the machine up when I attached it. Is that not the right way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to help, but I would also suggest posting to the AWS forum.  I've gotten very fast answers there, including from Amazon tech support folks.

Comment: It's fine to have the machine up.  You can attach and detach while the instance is running.  In any case, I'm not sure I can help.  I simply haven't had that issue arise and wouldn't know what to check.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure if it will be the reason in your case, but we found a similar problem while integrating Fedora images in our infrastructure for [BitNami Cloud Hosting](http://bitnami.org/cloud).

Some kernels use /dev/xvd* instead of /dev/sd*. In your case, if you have attached the volume with device name /dev/sdh it would appear as /dev/xvdh in the machine.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

When you attach a new EBS volume to an EC2 instance, there is nothing present on the volume, not even filesystem. Hence if you do `df -h`, it won't show up.

You should use `lsblk` command to list all the attached disks.

You will have to format it to make it usable. Here is the useful [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) for that.

Also, @CarlosSM's answer is correct that sometimes the name of the volume is different than what is specified.

Answer (score 9):

1. Use `lsblk | grep disk` to list all the volumes that are available.
2. You should be able to spot the EBS volume that is available and not mounted. For example, `nvme1n1     259:2    0  3.9T  0 disk`.
3. You should have `/dev/nvme1n1` available.
4. Create a mount-point, if need. For example, `# mkdir /my_ebs`
5. Mount the EBS volume. `# mount /dev/nvme1n1 /my_ebs`
6. `df` should list it now.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

@ajit-verma 's answer is incomplete, he forgot to format the filesystem.
Otherwise it's good.

Recap:

1. Log on as root: `sudo su -`
2. Identify the device name: `lsblk | grep disk`
3. Format the device: `mkfs -t xfs /dev/xvdf`
4. Mount it: `mkdir /var/data && chown ec2-user:ec2-user /var/data && mount /dev/xvdf /var/data`
5. Verify: `df -h`

Attention, don't think that if EC2 Volumes console show /dev/sdf, then your device is called the same. It's false. Follow Ajit's suggestion to find out the device name: `lsblk | grep disk`, then add /dev/ in front, to have your full device path.
e.g. `/dev/xvdf`